# In Rails, how can you return model data from multiple different ActiveModelSerializers/Models at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I have a couple models. Let's call them Widget and Gadget.

My #index for for Widget and Gadget looks something like this

```
def index
    widgets = Widget.all
    if widgets
        respond_with widgets, each_serializer: Api::V1::WidgetSerializer
    else
        render json: { message: [t(:not_found_widget)] }, status: :not_found
    end
end     

def index
    gadgets = Gadget.all
    if gadgets
        respond_with gadgets, each_serializer: Api::V1::GadgetSerializer
    else
        render json: { message: [t(:not_found_gadget)] }, status: :not_found
    end
end
```

And my serializers...

```
class Api::V1::WidgetSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :desc
end

 class Api::V1::GadgetSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :desc
end
```

However, I have the need for a resource that returns both of those in 1. I need both widgets and gadgets returned at once. So the json would look like...

```
{
    "widgets": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "desc": "One"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "desc": "Two"
        }
    ],
    "gadgets": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "desc": "One"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "desc": "Two"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve this. Something like

```
widgets = Widget.all
gadgets = Gadget.all
respond_with widgets, each_serializer: Api::V1::WidgetSerializer, gadgets, each_serializer: Api::V1::GadgetSerializer
```

However, this clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Serializer classes don't have to match AR models. Serializer classes should be used as your representation of your JSON you want to produce. In your example, let's assume to call a new serializer `DashboardSerializer`, then you can put both `widgets` and `gadgets` there:

```
class DashboardSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  self.root = false

  attributes :widgets, :gadgets

  def widgets
    Widget.all
  end

  def gadgets
    Gadget.all
  end
end
```

Comment: I have similar case but there is an issue that I need to get data on base of ID like Model.find course_id but how to pass id from my API to Serializer

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this working is if you had a model that has_many widgets and has_many gadgets with it's own serializer as AMS will apply the correct serializers to associations declared in a serializer.

something like

```
class Composite < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :widgets
 has_many :gadgets
end

class CompositeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :widgets
  has_many :gadgets
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to build a large json string manually of all the objects I want and return that? (Preferably minus the timestamps)